# Make GUD-GDB display source code always in the same window

Tags: emacs, window, gud

Using GUD-GDB, when I hit a breakpoint or navigate the stack trace, GUD executes the function `gud-display-line` to find a buffer to display the source code associated with that event. How can I add some type of advice to `gud-display-line` function in order for it to always use the same window and to not create windows everywhere ?

I tried searching extensively but did not found a solution. Also attempted some advices but to no end.

The goal is when I start a GUD session, to have two windows dedicated to debugging, one being the *gud* window and the other source code.